# Поместить данные из БД в объекты модели

Tags: java, sql

Есть четыре модели (ClassRoom, Pupil, PupilInClssRoom, Teacher), заполняю таблицы значениями и создаю связи, после этого делаю SELECT запрос на вывод нужных данных.

```
ResultSet resultSet = super.executeSqlValue(
            "SELECT p.name,p.surname,t.name,t.surname,t.discipline,c.name FROM pupils AS p " +
                    "INNER JOIN pupils_in_class_rooms AS in ON p.id = in.idPupils " +
                    "INNER JOIN teachers AS t ON t.id = in.idTeachers " +
                    "INNER JOIN class_rooms AS c ON c.id = in.idClassRooms");
```

и вывожу их в консоль

```
while (resultSet.next()) {

        String name = resultSet.getObject(1).toString();
        String surname = resultSet.getObject(2).toString();
        String nameTwo = resultSet.getObject(3).toString();
        String surnameTwo = resultSet.getObject(4).toString();
        String discipline = resultSet.getObject(5).toString();
        String className = resultSet.getObject(6).toString();
        System.out.println(name + " " + surname + " " + nameTwo + " " + surnameTwo + " " + discipline + " " + className);
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Создана таблица pupils_in_class_rooms
Создана таблица pupils
Создана таблица teachers
Создана таблица class_rooms
Создан вшений ключ class_rooms.id <- pupils_in_class_rooms.idClassRooms
Создан вшений ключ pupils.id <- pupils_in_class_rooms.idPupils
Создан вшений ключ teachers.id <- pupils_in_class_rooms.idTeachers
Запись добавлена 1 2A
Запись добавлена 1 Alla Aronova Russian
Запись добавлена 1 Oleg Ahmatov
Запись добавлена 2 Anastatia Davidova
Запись добавлена 3 Stas Shapovalov
Запись добавлена 1 1 1 1
Запись добавлена 2 2 1 1
Запись добавлена 3 3 1 1
Oleg Ahmatov Alla Aronova Russian 2A
Anastatia Davidova Alla Aronova Russian 2A
Stas Shapovalov Alla Aronova Russian 2A

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Как можно поместить данные из БД в объекты и вывести в консоль?

Класс Pupil

```
  public class Pupil extends BaseModel {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Pupil(long id, String name, String surname) throws SQLException {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        insert();
    }

    public Pupil() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void insert() throws SQLException {
        super.executeSqlStatement("INSERT INTO pupils (id,name,surname) VALUES " +
                        "(" + id + ",'" + name + "','" + surname + "')",
                "Запись добавлена " + id + " " + name + " " + surname);
    }
```

Таблица Pupils

```
public void selectValue() throws SQLException {

        List<Pupil> pupilList = new LinkedList<Pupil>();
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(1,"hello","world"));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(2,"hello","world"));
        pupilList.add(new Pupil(3,"hello","world"));

        ResultSet resultSet = super.executeSqlValue("SELECT p.id,p.name,p.surname FROM pupils AS p");

        while (resultSet.next()) { ;

              for (Pupil p : pupilList) {
                 p.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
                 p.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                 p.setSurname(resultSet.getString("surname"));
                 System.out.println(p.getId() + p.getName() + p.getSurname());
                  break;
              }
```

INSERT вызывается в конструкторе при создании экземпляра

Comment: Освоить одну из библиотек/фреймвёрков ORM. Например javaee продвигает JPA, но есть и другие. Spring например имеет как свои средства, облегчающие задачу, так и может использовать сторонние технологии (тот же JPA). Apache common dbutils тоже помогает создавать объекты из базы данных. Знакомство с подобным решением прольёт свет на то, как это работает и в более сложных системах.

Comment: @Sergey я пока наткнулся на паттерн DAO, он не реализуем без помощи вышеописанного?
Использую обычный драйвер БД

Comment: DAO - это, как я понимаю другое. Непосредственно записи из таблиц бд в объекты переводит ORM. А задача DAO - это определить удобные методы для извлечения данных. Эти методы в свою очередь могут использовать результаты ORM и неудобные специфические методы используемой системы бд. Примерно такой путь данных БД -> ORM -> DAO. Но чтобы посмотреть как работает БД -> ORM, не нужно отвлекаться на DAO

Answer (score 2):

Элементарно. Вспомните что такое классы в java и как они создаются

```
public class Pupil {
    private String name;
    ...

    public Pupil(String name, String surname, ...) {
        this.name = name;
        ...
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    ...

}

while (resultSet.next()) {
    Pupil pupil = new Pupil(
        resultSet.getObject(1).toString(),
        resultSet.getObject(2).toString(),
        ...
    );
    // можно установить свойства с помощью сетера
    pupil.setClassName(resultSet.getObject(6).toString());
    
    System.out.printf("name %s surname %s ...", pupil.getName(), pupil.getSurname(), ...);
}
```

Comment: да, я вот тоже об этом подумал)

Comment: но тут вопрос где вызывать INSERT, иначе он говорит, что pupil null, можно попробовать сделать пустой конструктор и в метод INSERT на вход подать id,name и тд

Comment: INSERT - похоже связан с обратным вопросом: как данные из модели поместить в базу. Соответственно решается в обратном порядке. Для начала должен быть заполненный pupil и никакой не null. И действительно его свойства используются в формировании запроса INSERT

Comment: щас покажу до чего я додумался вчера, но мне кажется это не совсем оно, отредактирую топик

Comment: Так не делается. Готовый экземпляр модели подаётся в метод dao или orm. И только этот метод обращается к бд с запросом insert на основе переданной модели. new Pupil -> ORM -> БД. Есть ещё такой шаблон ActiveRecord. Там сама модель общается с бд. Но даже там для этого отводятся специальные методы, но никак не конструктор, если я не ошибаюсь